# How to export phonegap local database data into csv/excel file in android app?

Tags: android, cordova, csv, local-database

I have developed a phonegap app on android, 
which uses local database API to store data locally.

I am using web services to upload that data to server.
This works fine.

Today I came across a situation, 
wherein a client asked me to provide facility to export locally stored data into csv/excel file and store that file at easily accessible location in device.

I searched this on Google but, have not found any solution. :(

Anyone have any idea, How to export phonegap local database data into csv/excel file in android app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We faced some problem so Please if you got output please inform to me

Comment: @PavanAlapati: We couldn't find a solution to this, so we provided a workaround as exporting a data from the server itself.